# How to change the display of the scale of a "hours:minutes" variable in plot?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying change the scale of my y-axis plot.

The main difficulty is that my y-axis is not regular integers but hours:minutes kind of variable.

My problem is that I don't know how to break or re-scale my y-axis properly.

Let's take a look at a reproducible example:

```
# Let's create 15 observations: 15 betime sleep on 15 different days
data <- data.frame(dates = as.POSIXct(c("2019-07-21 01:00:00","2019-07-22 00:45:00","2019-07-23 02:30:00","2019-07-24 23:30:00","2019-07-25 22:45:00","2019-07-26 21:45:00","2019-07-27 23:45:00","2019-07-28 00:45:00","2019-07-29 01:30:00","2019-07-30 02:45:00","2019-07-31 02:35:00","2019-08-01 00:20:00","2019-08-02 23:55:00","2019-08-03 23:15:00","2019-08-04 01:15:00")))

# Let's create a variable that only takes hours:minutes
data$bedtimes <- format(data$date, format = "%H:%M:%S")
data$bedtimes <- as.POSIXct(data$bedtimes, format = "%H:%M:%S")

# Now let's plot the hours:minutes bedtime for each day
plot(data$date,data$bedtimes, xlab = "Date in Month Day", ylab = "Bedtime in Hours and minutes")
```

Now, here is the output of our plot:

[image]

As you can see the y-axis (The Bed time hours and minutes) is starting at the bottom from midnight `00:00` to `24:00` on the top.

My problem is that this plot is not really making sense visually.

I would like my y-axis, to start from, let's say `12:00` (24-hour clock time type) at the bottom, to then midnight `00:00` in the middle, to finally  `11:59` at the top. So from bottom to top we have actually 24 hours, just not in the same order than before.

How can I do that?

Comment: Not directly related, but why are you creating 15 vectors of 1 date each, instead of just 1 vector of 15 dates? You also don't need to create a vector, then create a data frame. Just say `data <- data.frame(dates = as.POSIXct(c("date1", "date2", "date3",...)))` and you've made your data frame in 1 line instead of 17

Comment: Also, you say you want midnight in the middle and 12am at the top. Those are the same...? Do you mean 12pm (noon) at the top?

Comment: @camille I though it would be more readable (edit done). When I say 12:00 (PM) I mean 12:00 in a 24-hour clock scheme at the bottom. 00h00 at the middle. And 11h59 at the top (edit done too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this closer to what you are looking for? Start with the original data without adding the bedtimes:

```
hours <- as.numeric(format(data$date, "%H")) + as.numeric(format(data$date, "%M"))/60
flip <- ifelse(hours > 12, hours - 12, hours + 12)
oldp <- par(mar=c(5.1, 6.1, 4.1, 2.1))
plot(data$date, flip, , ylim=c(0, 24), xlab="Date", ylab="", yaxt="n")
title(ylab="Bedtime", line=5)
axis(2, c(0, 6, 12, 18, 24), c("Noon", "6pm", "Midnight", "6am",
     "Noon"), las=1)
abline(h=12, lty=2)
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: No unfortunately, not really. As you can see, the different points of the scatter plot are very far away from each other. My goal is to bring them closer because it make more sense visually. You go to sleep, let's say, between 22:00 (so 10:00PM) and 03:00 (so 03:00AM). My goal is to visually have these observations come closer to the middle point of the y-axis, which I would like to be midnight.

Comment: More like this?

Comment: Exactly! So I see that you need to convert hours:minutes into integers. It is not possible to keep the hours:minutes variable as it is?

Comment: The conversion is only needed for plotting. Your original timestamp is not affected. There is no way to plot 10:30pm without converting to numeric values since the plotting function only takes numeric data. You can label the y-axis with anything you want if you use `axis()`. I converted to a 24 hour with decimal minutes, but then we have to center the values around 0/24 hours to plot them in the middle of the graph.